# PHP Loop row Value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just a newbie and I have tried my best to figure out on how to solve my problem but I really can't get it.

I just want to know how to get the `primary key/foreign key` value of the current row in my loop. In my current code, I get the `primary key` of the last row. I have tried `$_POST[subject_id]` and `$_SESSION[subject_id]` and nothing happens.
Please help me. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

This is my php file.

```
dbconn();
$sql = "select student_id, lastname ||', '|| firstname ||' '|| middlename as
    name, contact_no from tbl_student where student_id in (select student_id
    from tbl_student_block)";
dbclose();
echo "<center>";
insertListMenu ("Select Student: ", "student", $sql." order by name",
    "student_id", "name", "StudSearch", "Search");
echo "</center>";
echo "<br/>";
$student_id = $_POST['student'];
if (($_POST['StudSearch']) == 'Search'){
    dbconn();
    $rs = pg_query("select sj.*, SUM(p.paid_amount) as Total,
    sj.subject_fee - SUM(p.paid_amount) as Balance from tbl_subject as sj,
    tbl_payment_details as p, tbl_student as s, tbl_student_block as sb
    where p.student_block_id = sb.student_block_id and
    s.student_id = sb.student_id and sj.subject_id = sb.subject_id
    and sb.student_id = ".$student_id."
    group by sj.subject_id order by sj.subject_id;");
    displayRecordset($rs);
    dbclose();
}
    $_SESSION['studID'] = $_POST['student'];
if (isset($_POST['Payment']) && ($_POST['Payment'] == 'Add Payment')){
    dbconn();
    $rsbookedit = pg_query("select sj.description, sj.subject_fee,
    SUM(p.paid_amount) as Total, sj.subject_fee - SUM(p.paid_amount) as Balance
    from tbl_subject as sj, tbl_payment_details as p, tbl_student as s,
    tbl_student_block as sb where p.student_block_id = sb.student_block_id
    and s.student_id = sb.student_id and sj.subject_id = sb.subject_id
    and sb.student_id = ".$_SESSION['studID']." and
    sb.subject_id = '".$_SESSION['subID']."' group by sj.subject_id
    order by sj.subject_id;");

    $r2 = pg_fetch_array($rsbookedit, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);
    echo var_dump($r2);
    dbclose();
}
```

This is my loop:

```
<?php
    $counter = 1;
    while ($r = pg_fetch_array($rs, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['subject_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['subject_fee']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['total']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $r['balance']; ?></td>
    <td>
<?php
    if ($r['balance'] > 0){
?>
        <input type="submit" name="Payment" value="Add Payment" />
<?php
    }
    else
        echo "PAID";
?>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    $_SESSION['subID'] = $r['subject_id'];
    $counter++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: $_POST won't work without a form submission. $_SESSION won't work unless you call session_start() at the beginning of every page in your site

Comment: I have a form submission and the session_start at the very top of my code. I just didn't add it here because it will be too long.

Comment: i notice in your post you say you use $_SESSION[subject_id] but in your code it's $_SESSION[subID]. if one of those ins't a typo, that could be your issue, if you're storing it in subID, but trying to retrieve it using subject_id

Comment: It's not a typo. I've been trying to get both the `student_id` and `subject_id`, `student_id`'s just fine but I'm having a problem getting the `subject_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `PGSQL_BOTH on the line` or you can leave that parameter as blank because it is optional

```
while ($r = pg_fetch_array($rs, NULL, PGSQL_BOTH)){
```